# i cant get the image cover my whole jumbotron with text over it. Here is my html and CSS

Tags: html, css

i cant get the image cover my whole jumbotron with text over it. Here is my html and CSS. Im trying to get the whole image; "img/newyork.jpg" cover my jumbotron. I know there is an easy way but i cant figure what im missing. Please help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
<title> Marketing Plus </title> 
</head>
<body> 
<div class="header">
      <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav">
          <div class="logo">
    <img src="img/logo_mplus.png" alt="logo for marketing plus">
  </div>  
          <li>Contact</li>
          <li>Industries</li>
          <li>Company</li>
          <li>Home</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container">  
        <div class="main">
          <img src="img/newyork.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
          <div class="container" id="content">
    <div class="row">
        Marketing Plus
    </div>
</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript --> 
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
</body> 
</html> 
</html>

/*CSS starts here*/

.nav {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 20px 0;
      }

      .nav li {
        color: 00000;
        display: inline;
        font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 12px;
        margin-right: 25px;
        text-transform: uppercase;

      }

.logo img {
  margin-left:120px;
      margin-right:auto;
      margin-top:0px;
      border:0px ridge #E80000;
      background-image: url("img/logo_mplus.png");
      background-size:199px 101px;
      width:199px;
      height:101px;
      background-repeat:no-repeat;
      background-position:center;
      float: left;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;

}

li {
    float: right;
    padding: 10px;

}

.container {
        max-width: 940px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0 10px;
      }




      .img-responsive {
        background: url(img/newyork.jpg);
        background-size: cover;

}
```

Comment: Jumbotrons and containers have padding and so you cannot   fill an image using `img` try applying `background-image` to jumbotron

Comment: you're using the image tag to insert the background, move it to the ´jumbotron as @JonesJoseph has stated

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your replies. Im sorry but what do you mean move it to jumbotron? like this; 

<div class="jumbotron" img src="img/logo_mplus.png" alt="logo for marketing plus">